# Python :Anything wrong with this code: Used explicit wait for the one webelement:

Tags: python

I am using the simple account creation for Facebook.

The below code is not working:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Create New Account']"))).click()
```

This code works:

```py
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Create New Account']").click()
```

I have created an explicit wait for the web element "Create New Account". Not sure why it is not working. Can anyone look into this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does it still not work if you try something other than XPATH?

Answer (score -1):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects1\pythonProject\pythonSelFramework\tests\faceBookAccoutCreation.py", line 17, in 
driver.find_element_by_name("firstname").send_keys("xyz")

I am seeing the above error. I haven't tried anything other than xpath.

Step to reproduce:

1. login to https://www.facebook.com/
2. Click on create an account
3. When I click to 'create an account' it takes 3 secs to open the window. I am using explicit wait for the element using the explicit path.

When I use the debug mode except for this step rest of all the steps executed successfully.

Comment: `Stackoverflow` is not normal `Forum` but `Q&A` portal - and here is place for answer/solution, not for new information. You should put new information in original question. Downvote.

Comment: BTW your error message shows problem with `"firstname"`, not with `"Create New Account"` so you have problem in different place then you think. You use `wait` with `"Create New Account"` but you should use it with `"firstname"`.